# An alternating series convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

I was wondering whether the following series converges or diverges,

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \sqrt[n]{a}$$ $$\forall a>0,  a\ne1$$

The divergence test cannot be applied, since the sequence does not have a limit.

Comment: If $a\gt 1$, all the terms have absolute value $\gt 1$. If $0\lt a\lt 1$, all the terms have absolute value $\ge a$. In particular, the absolute value of the terms does not have limit $0$, so we have divergence.

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n (1- \sqrt[n]{a})$ is convergent, right? And $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n 1$ is divergent,  So$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \sqrt[n]{a}$ looks like it should be divergent, But I do not know the order in which you sum the terms.

Answer (score 4):

Since $$\lim_{n \to \infty} (-1)^n \sqrt[n]{a} \neq 0$$
the series is not convergent.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\sqrt[n]a \to 1$, hence $(-1)^n \sqrt[n]a \not\to 0$, so the series diverges.